# How to build a app lock application using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pubspec

I am looking to create a application using flutter that  can put locks on  other apps according to users choice. So can anyone tell me how to do this using flutter ? Is there any plugins out there ?

The app must work like this "when someone opens a locked app it should show a lock screen before opening the app, if the password is correct the application will be opened else it should show the password is incorrect".

Comment: Good question and welcome to StackOverflow!

Have you try the `local_auth` plugins yet? https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Comment: This question has too large of a scope. StackOverflow does not exist to design your whole app.
On another note, Flutter is not a great choice for an app like this, which relies on deep system integration.

Comment: @JohnMelodyMe Thanks for the plugin ! But how can I show a  lock screen before opening the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this AppLock application using flutter, it depends on method channel and USAGE_STATS. hope this will solve your problem.

[visit](https://github.com/Ninad7n/AppLockFlutter)